# Can I get Editor and cursorLocation without image-added handler in vue2 editor

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, quill

This is how vue-editor is working as of now.

```html
<vue-editor
  class="editor"
  v-model="blogContent"
  :editor-toolbar="customToolbar" 
  useCustomImageHandler
  @image-added="imageHandler"
  @focus="onFocus"
  ref="editor"
/>
```

Image handler function

```js
imageHandler(file, Editor, cursorLocation, resetUploader) {
  Editor.insertEmbed(cursorLocation, 'image', imageUrl)
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is in place of using the image add button from the toolbar I want to use an external button that will open a modal with various images and from that I can select the image to get its URL. Then on clicking an insert button it should insert the image on the cursor location like we are doing in the above function. For this I need Editor and cursorLocation parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to my own question.
The Editor and cursorLocation can be accessed through ref in **vue-editor** component.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="insertPhoto">Insert Photo</button>
    <client-only>
      <vue-editor class="editor" v-model="blogContent" ref="editor" @focus="onFocus"
    /></client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
let VueEditor
if (process.client) {
  VueEditor = require('vue2-editor').VueEditor
}
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      blogContent: null,
      customToolbar: [
        [{ header: [false, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] }],
        ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
        [{ align: '' }, { align: 'center' }, { align: 'right' }, { align: 'justify' }],
        ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
        [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
        [{ script: 'sub' }, { script: 'super' }],
        [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
        ['link'],
      ],
      quill: null,
      imageURL: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$refs.editor.quill.focus() //You should use this directly in the function for modal opening. This is just for demo.
    }, 2000)
  },
  components: { VueEditor },
  methods: {
    onFocus(quill) {
      this.quill = quill
    },
    async insertPhoto() {
      //Set your own image URL
      this.imageURL =
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1637824504309-6dc3a16173c5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=10'

      const Editor = this.quill
      const range = Editor.getSelection()
      const cursorLocation = await range.index
      await Editor.editor.insertEmbed(cursorLocation, 'image', this.imageURL)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```